# compute the minimum L1 distance of rows between two matrices in julia

Tags: math, matrix, julia, distance

I have two matrices

```
A = {1,2,3,3,2,2;
2,2,2,2,3,1;
2,2,2,2,2,2}

B = {2,2,2,2,3,1;
2,2,2,2,2,2;
1,2,3,3,2,2}
```

I want to compute the minimum L1 distance/city block distance for each of the rows between `A` and `B`, such that

```
minimum_distance_function(A,B)
= 0
```

The dimensions for the matrices I have are actually 800x39 and I'm not sure how to compute this minimum distance quickly!

Answer (score 1):

```
using Distances

A = [1 2 3 3 2 2;
     2 2 2 2 3 1;
     2 2 2 2 2 2]

B = [2 2 2 2 3 1;
     2 2 2 2 2 2;
     1 2 3 3 2 2]

findmin(pairwise(Cityblock(), A', B'))
```

The last statement returns:

```
julia> findmin(pairwise(Cityblock(), A', B'))
(0, CartesianIndex(2, 1))
```

where `0` is the minimum and `CartesianIndex(2,1)` is a pair of rows which obtain it.

This solution may not scale well to too many rows, in that case, splitting the work into row blocks of one matrix will reduce memory demands (and is a little more involved).

Finally, for really big instances, some sort of hierarchical clustering may be the way to go. There is much literature on such problems. But the simple solution above should suffice, or even just a double `for` loop on rows would do.